# Dating recent skeletons with radiometric dating techniques

Tags: fossils, dating

Can we use radiometric dating techniques on recent skeletons from, say, around the year 2000 and so on and get the same result as the recorded date of death of the owner of the skeleton? If yes (or no), why?

Comment: Such young bones are examined by other means. But it might be possible, there are various shorter decaying isotopes, but experts give better results (and they are cheaper).

Comment: It depends the circumstances. Because of the amount of C14 introduced into the atmosphere by atmospheric nuclear testing in the 1950s & 1960s the technique was used to ascertain the year of birth of woman found dead under suspicious circumstance in [Oslo, in 1995](https://unsolved.com/gallery/death-in-oslo/).